# java.io.EOFException between sendRedirect() and ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java

the problem  is that it launch a `java.io.EOFException` in the server side when i try to do `ois = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());`

```
private void writeObjectStream(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeChars("x");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtil.closeQuietly(oos, ois);
    }
}
```

the call of writeObjectStream :

```
....    
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
                response.setHeader("Location", "www.sample.com");
                response.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + 500);
                writeObjectStream(request, response);
                return true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object streams have a particular format and if you are reading something which was not in the format you can easily confuse it. Each type of data you write/read with this type of stream has a tag and if the tag doesn't match the expected one the exception thrown is an EOFException.  This is confusing in my opinion give it can throw a StreamCorruptedException in a different context and that would be more appropriate.

In short, you are trying to read something which is not an ObjectInputStream, or the data you are reading not the right type, or it is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an ObjectOutputStream just to call writeChars(). Use a DataOutputStream, and a DataInputStream at the other end.

Comment: it's just an example , in the real case i will use a serialize bean

Comment: It's just a pointless example that doesn't demonstrate the problem and uses irrelevant code.